# Spring Configuration Conditional On Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I want my `@Configuration` to not be active during tests with `@SpringBootTest`.

Is there any configuration property or bean active automatically in every test to detect if the `ApplicationContext` is in test?

For example:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(TestEntityManager.class)
```

But I can't use `TestEntityManager` because that is only in a `@DataJpaTest` context.

I want to avoid going into every `@SpringBootTest` and doing configurations for each.

Comment: Use `type` instead of the default `value`. Type takes a String which must contain the FQN of the class. So `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type="org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager")` should do the trick.

Comment: I don't want to use `TestEntityManager` though. I need something available for every `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: @George Did you consider using "test" profile? If you activate such profile in your tests then you'll be able to define "test only" beans or disable "non-test" beans.

Comment: There is no common bean I can think of. I would suggest using a profile for those tests and disable/enable on that.

Comment: The problem with adding a custom property or profile is that I need to modify all existing tests, and I also have to remember to add the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on any future tests.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging, I think I found a common bean that only exists in the test context:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor")
```